# Browser Resize event for sticky navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window, sticky

I've been dealing with this problem since days now and I hope somebody here can help me.
I'm trying to make a sticky navigation and a 100% height header (body and html are set to 100% height too). Basically the problem I have is that the sticky navigation only works well after the page is (re)loaded. However scrolling after having resized the browser's window makes the navigation either jump to early or to late to the fixed position at the very top.
I'd need to implement a resize event I guess, so that the calculation of the variable "navOffset" fires everytime the window is resized, right?
I tried many ways of inserting this into my code which are also explained in the link below, but I falied everytime.
I hope somebody can disclose this secret to me as I'm getting insane about this.

Thanks a lot and have a great week!

Sascha

Example of the effect I want to achieve:
http://html5-webdesign.berlin/

Tutorials, which didn't help me:
https://stackoverflow.com/…/jquery-combine-document-ready-an…

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;

jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
} else {
jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your second function (which you should probably name) and add it to the window resize event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;

jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());

function setPosition() {
var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
} else {
jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
}
}

jQuery(window).scroll(setPosition);

jQuery(window).resize(setPosition);
});
```

Comment: Hi @firefoxuser_1,

thank you very much for your answer. I just tried out the new code, but unfortunately the navigation still keeps jumping around after I resize the window, whereas when I then reload the page in that new window size it works well again. I don't know what the problem could be... Maybe there's a conflict with some CSS rules like html, body {
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}